# Indesign CS6 import xml content in document textframe content

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I am having problems with element placement on document

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var productXML = new XML (xmlString);
        alert(productXML.children().length());
        x1=0;
        y1=0;
        x2=25;
        y2=25;
            for(myCounter = 0; myCounter < productXML.children().length(); myCounter++){
               alert(productXML.product[myCounter].name);
               element = myDocument.pages.item(0).textFrames.add(); 
                element.geometricBounds = [x1,y1,x2,y2]; 
                y1 = y1+25;
               element.contents = productXML.product[myCounter].name;
            }
```

In above code, i get error with

y1 = y1+25; 
and 
element.contents = productXML.product[myCounter].name;

the product name comes correct when i display it in alert but i can not assign it to contents. and changing x-y positions also throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just typecasting problem.... got it now